# Retrieve HTTP Body in NanoHTTPD

Tags: java, nanohttpd

How can I retrieve the HTTP `POST` request body when implementing [NanoHTTPD](http://nanohttpd.com)s `serve` method?

I've tried to use the `getInputStream()` method of `IHTTPSession` already, but I always get an `SocketTimeoutException` when using it inside of the `serve` method.

Comment: How can I get parameters from the URL using the GET method?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In the `serve` method you first have to call `session.parseBody(files)`, where `files` is a `Map<String, String>`, and then `session.getQueryParameterString()` will return the `POST` request's body.

I found [an example](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/blob/852318439539b54ee6b4ce048df63b6c12cf0417/core/src/main/java/fi/iki/elonen/NanoHTTPD.java#L300) in the source code. Here is the relevant code:

```
public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
    Map<String, String> files = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Method method = session.getMethod();
    if (Method.PUT.equals(method) || Method.POST.equals(method)) {
        try {
            session.parseBody(files);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            return new Response(Response.Status.INTERNAL_ERROR, MIME_PLAINTEXT, "SERVER INTERNAL ERROR: IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
        } catch (ResponseException re) {
            return new Response(re.getStatus(), MIME_PLAINTEXT, re.getMessage());
        }
    }
    // get the POST body
    String postBody = session.getQueryParameterString();
    // or you can access the POST request's parameters
    String postParameter = session.getParms().get("parameter");

    return new Response(postBody); // Or postParameter.
}
```

Comment: any reason `session.parseBody(files)` has to be called before `session.getQueryParameterString()` ?

Comment: @vatsa I had a quick look at the source code: when dealing with non multipart/form-data requests, session.parseBody(files) reads the POST request's body and [calls HTTPSession's decodeParms()](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/blob/852318439539b54ee6b4ce048df63b6c12cf0417/core/src/main/java/fi/iki/elonen/NanoHTTPD.java#L1005) method, which sets the queryParameterString and parms field values to the POST's body. Without the call to session.parseBody() these fields are empty.

Answer (score 32):

On a `IHTTPSession` instance you can call the `.parseBody(Map<String, String>)` method which will then fill the map you provided with some values.

Afterwards your map may contain a value under the key `postBody`.

```
        final HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        session.parseBody(map);
        final String json = map.get("postData");
```

This value will then hold your posts body.

[Code that does this, can be found here.](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/blob/fe8be79fa8d8b131d5d39e77ae0baabd177d5ec1/core/src/main/java/fi/iki/elonen/NanoHTTPD.java#L1024)

Comment: By far the best solution, especially when using JSON.

Comment: take note that if the Content-Type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`,  the content of the parameters is found under `session.getParms()` instead of the `map` object that you supply

Comment: The only solution that worked for me when the `content-type` is `application/json`

Comment: @Rinmalavi thanks for posting the link to the code where it is clear `files.put("postData", postLine);` one will need to use `postData` to get the data...but does any have any links to this in document form?

Comment: @CrandellWS From what I remember using this back in '14, documentation was mostly code itself. Not sure if the things changed. Sorry for no answer.

Comment: How do you mock sesssion.parseBody(map)

Answer (score 12):

I think `session.getQueryParameterString();` not work in this case.

If you using `POST`, `PUT`, you should want to try this code:

```
Integer contentLength = Integer.parseInt(session.getHeaders().get("content-length"));
byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLength];
session.getInputStream().read(buffer, 0, contentLength);
Log.d("RequestBody: " + new String(buffer));
```

In fact, I tried `IOUtils.toString(inputstream, encoding)` but it cause `Timeout exception`!

Comment: `session.getHeaders().get("content-length")` == null?

Comment: this is better than others when post data is not in plain string format

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am getting my post response body with NanoHttp, and it works for me. Very important to note that if you are handling your own error response codes and want to send a body use the error input stream instead of the conn.getInputStream() This will avoid the file not found exception or broken pipe exception if close the connection before the server sent the body.

```
 public HashMap<String, Object> getResponse(HttpURLConnection conn) throws IOException {

        Log.i("STATUS", String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
        Log.i("MSG", conn.getResponseMessage());

        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        BufferedReader br;

        if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
             br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        else
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream()));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            response.append(line);

        conn.disconnect();
        return new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), HashMap.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used this method and worked for me without socket exception.

```java
String body = "";

try {
    Map<String, String> headers = session.getHeaders();
    if (headers == null || headers.get("content-length") == null) {
        iDoMethodInThread.onException(new Exception("No Content length found in header"));
        return;
    }
    int contentLength = Integer.parseInt(headers.get("content-length"));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLength];
    int totalRead = 0;
    while (totalRead < contentLength) {
        int read = session.getInputStream().read(buffer, totalRead, contentLength - totalRead);
        if (read == -1) {
            break;
        }
        totalRead += read;
    }
    body = new String(buffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).