# NanoHTTPD - Cannot access Response class

Tags: java, android, nanohttpd

I'm following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22349772/retrieve-http-body-in-nanohttpd) on SO because I want to handle POST requests with NanoHTTPD. When I put it into my `MainActivity` class in Android Studio, it gives me an error:

> 'Response(fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD.Response.lStatus,java.lang.String,java.io.lnputStream, long)’ has protected access in 'fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD.Response'

There's no quick fix suggested by Android Studio, unfortunately, so how would I fix this?

My code:

```
public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
    Map<String, String> files = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Method method = session.getMethod();
    if (Method.PUT.equals(method) || Method.POST.equals(method)) {
        try {
            session.parseBody(files);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            return new Response(Response.Status.INTERNAL_ERROR, MIME_PLAINTEXT, "SERVER INTERNAL ERROR: IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
        } catch (ResponseException re) {
            return new Response(re.getStatus(), MIME_PLAINTEXT, re.getMessage());
        }
    }
    // get the POST body
    String postBody = session.getQueryParameterString();
    // or you can access the POST request's parameters
    String postParameter = session.getParms().get("parameter");

    return new Response(postBody); // Or postParameter.
}
```

Comment: Post minimal code that demonstrates the problem. We will not dig through your link.

Comment: @greenapps Changed

Comment: A compile time error. Which statement is causing it? Why do you let us guess?

Comment: @greenapps Every time it mentions the "Response" class, so every "new Response" is highlighted.

Answer (score 4):

You can use: newFixedLengthResponse to replace new Response, like:
newFixedLengthResponse("Hello").